# rsync 'flip' characterization

Tags: ssh, rsync, encryption

I ran across an example pair where there was an original and a 'flip' version:

Original

```
rsync -aHAXxv --numeric-ids --delete --progress -e "ssh -T -c arcfour -o Compression=no -x" user@<source>:<source_dir> <dest_dir>
```

"Flip"

```
rsync -aHAXxv --numeric-ids --delete --progress -e "ssh -T -c arcfour -o Compression=no -x" [source_dir] [dest_host:/dest_dir]
```

The [example](https://gist.github.com/KartikTalwar/4393116) seems to be identical right up to the point of the final quotation mark.

What is the second example labeled flip and how is it functionally different from the 'original'?   Are the two commands functionally equivalent?

Comment: You can't expect to understand if you omit part of the line. The “flip” line has `[source_dir] [dest_host:/dest_dir]` at the end, whereas the “original” line has `user@<source>:<source_dir> <dest_dir>`. As you can see, which of the two operands has a `something:` prefix has been [flipped](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flip#Verb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original author did a sloppy write-up and then you omitted part of what he wrote.

He wrote:

```
rsync ... user@<source>:<source_dir> <dest_dir>

rsync ... [source_dir] [dest_host:/dest_dir]
```

but it would have been better to write:

```
rsync ... user@<source_host>:<source_dir> <dest_dir>

rsync ... <source_dir> user@<dest_host>:<dest_dir>
```

And then the "flip" would have been much more obvious.

Basically, the first form "pulls" the files from the remote "source" host to the local "dest" host, and the second form "pushes" the files from the local source to the remote dest. He doesn't mention which is faster.

I also think he's wrong to omit the -z option. I use it all the time and I get fantastic speedup.

And while we're being pedantic, you can also do these:

```
rsync ... <source_dir> <dest_dir>

rsync ... user@<source_host>:<source_dir> user@<dest_host>:<dest_dir>
```

The first is just a local copy; you might want to use it in circumstances where `cp`, `ditto`, etc. don't have the options you want. The second form would let you copy files between two remote servers.

Finally, if we're being *really* pedantic, the -AX arguments are Linux-only AFAICT.

Comment: Excellent post.  The -z option is counter-intuitive: I am inspired to give it go.